# Warning while setting up PushNotificationIOS on foreground in React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting the following warning on Xcode while [setting up foreground push notification on IOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios):

```
Assigning to 'id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate> _Nullable' 
from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const __strong'
```

this warning appears on the last line of this snippet:

```
// Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
```

My app compiles and runs as expected. I have no experience with objective-c, so I have no idea what this is about. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you found the solution for your issue? Otherwise can you post your .h file where you should find something like `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to my AppDelegate interfaces:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

Comment: Also add #import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h> to the AppDelegate.h